# Statistics for (past) active wifi connections in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless-networking

Is there a way to see statistics of the past wifi connections established in Ubuntu ?
I am looking for something like,

## wifi name 1

### connection established at | lost at

- june 1 - 12 pm | june 1 - 1 pm

  april 29th - 11 am | april 29th 11:30 am

  april 29th - 9 am | april 29th 10:01 am

  jan 1 - 9 pm | jan 2 - 11 pm

Similarly for other wifi names ..